# Connection keeps closing in VS2005 Report Designer

Tags: visual-studio-2005, ssrs-2008, bids, report-designer

I'm trying to design a report in VS2005 BIDS Report Designer, but every so often, I haven't figured out any regular action that might cause it, but when I try and run the query, I get the following error:

> An error occurred while retrieving the
>   parameters in the query.
>   DeriveParameters requires an open and
>   available Connection. The connection's
>   current state is closed

What causes this and what can I do to open the connection again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having searched the interwbes for this same problem, the answer validated on my part, is to close and reopen the Visual Studio solution.